# PostgreSQL WITH query, execution order

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to update/delete from a table, then return the updated data via an inner join like this:

```
WITH removed AS (
  DELETE FROM cart
  WHERE cart.id = 1
  RETURNING *
)

SELECT cart.id, product.name, product.descr, product.price, cart.quantity
FROM cart INNER JOIN product
ON cart.product_id = product.id
WHERE cart.user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM removed);
```

However, it seems that the main `SELECT` query is returning before delete, so the changes are not reflected. From what I've read in the [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html) documentation:

> The sub-statements in `WITH` are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query.

Is there an alternative method I could use to return the select statement after the update/deletion from the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you quoted [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) yourself (though pointing to the outdated Postgres 9.1), changes made in CTEs of the same statement are not visible in the underlying tables.

I suggest this workaround:

```sql
WITH removed AS (
   DELETE FROM cart
   WHERE id = 1
   RETURNING user_id
   )
SELECT c.id, p.name, p.descr, p.price, c.quantity
FROM   cart c
JOIN   product p ON c.product_id = p.id
WHERE  c.user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM removed);
AND    c.cart.id <> 1;  --  repeat negated filter from above
```

[`<>` is the "not equal" operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-OP-TABLE) and the opposite of `=`. `cart.id <> 1` excludes the row(s) to be deleted with `WHERE id = 1`.

Else, you need two separate statements (nested in the same transaction). The second (SELECT) would then see effects of the first. You just have to remember the affected `user_id` somehow ...